How to view location access detailed information in Windows 11?
Using event viewer and resource monitor I am trying to find the exact details of what is constantly checking my location and how to stop it.
Example: Recently a dev of a web app (a PWA app he mentions) I was using was asked to find out why this was happening as it was showing in “privacy & security > location,” in Windows seemingly sporadically and very often.
He said he "fixed" it but now it just comes in as generic Microsoft Edge.
I want to see IP info, MAC address, etc, all the way I can block this.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i keep re-reading it, it seems very clear that i need help to view detailed info on location requests to and from this pc.

I don’t believe that information can be seen. In most cases the location shown in similar cases are not exact, as geolocation on an ip address, isn’t and has never been highly accurate. You would have to use something like Wiregaurd to discover the ip address in order to block it

This question is similar to: Which events in Event Viewer show which programs accessed my location?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
